# When to close Client and Node in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, client

Being new to elastic search I have few questions on it related to best practices for closing Client and Node and in which situations we need to close them. I am using elasticsearch java api for it.

```
public static Node elasticSearchNode = null;
public static Client elasticSearchClient = null;
```

I am declaring both node and client as static and in static get client method, I am checking that if its NULL then create new node or new client. So currently I am not closing Node and Client at any location in code.

I am using same client in all locations like indexing documents as well as searching.

Can you please tell me if its a right approach? or do I have to close them at some locations and where?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383544/elasticsearch-why-call-close-on-client-or-node